# How to test for multiple map items in Composer using python?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, print-composer

I am building a QGIS plugin and I need to check for multiple maps items in Composer that works on all platforms.  Currently I am getting the first map in the composition using the code below, but would rather have something which tests for multiple map items:

```
composerList = self.iface.activeComposers()
composerView = composerList[0]
composition = composerView.composition()
map = composition.getComposerMapById(0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a list of items in the composition with the items() method, and then test the item type using type(), so something along these lines should work:

```
maps = [item for item in composition.items() if item.type() == QgsComposerItem.ComposerMap]
```

To be exact, you may want to use:

```
maps = [item for item in composition.items() if item.type() == QgsComposerItem.ComposerMap and item.scene()]
```

Otherwise there's a chance you'll get maps which have been deleted from the composition (these are still kept around so that deleting items can be undone).